# Why did Vamana punish Mahabali

Tags: vamana, bali

Why did Vamana punish king Mahabali when he was the great king and his subjects were happy? Is it purely because he was Asura? Any explanations from scriptures?

Comment: You can read Srimad Bhagavata [eighth Kanda](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/) chapter 15 onwards. After being formerly defeated by Indra, Maharaja Bali conquers Swarga, which deeply pains Aditi, the devatas mother. She appeases Bhagwan Vishnu to make the devatas regain their lost position. Thus it was to fulfill the boon given to Aditi.

Comment: Great. Thank you